# Ubuntu Mate 22.04: System shuts down after it was suspended

Tags: suspend, power-management, shutdown, 22.04, ubuntu-mate

### Summary of the problem

I close the lid of my notebook and it seems to me that it's suspended correctly as it is configured in power management.

If I opened the lid after a while, I'd expect my notebook to automatically wake up and ask for the password. However it does not wake up and when I press the power button, it's booting instead of resuming from suspend-state.

### Additional information

I noticed that if there is an app with unsaved changes that blocks shutdown, the problem does not occur. In this case, my system wakes up after opening the lid, asks for the password and I see the application shows the dialog it usually shows when it's closed (or system is shut down) and there are unsaved changes.
=> This is why I assume that the system is actually shutting down after it's suspended.

There's one more thing: If I close the lid and open it after a short while (like 50seconds or something) the problem does also not occur. In this case, the system seems to smoothly resume from suspend after the lid is opened. However, there is no prompt for the password. But I think this is intended, that the system is not locked, if it's shut down for a short while like a minute or something.
=> this is why I wonder, if maybe the problem might be related to the fact that the supsended system should be locked.

### Affected system

- Dell XPS 13 9350
- Intel i5-6200U with HD Graphics 520
- Ubuntu Mate 22.04 LTS 64 Bit
- Kernel Linux 5.15.0-37-generic x86_64
- MATE 1.26.0
- Ubuntu-Mate was just installed. No upgrade performed.

Comment: Update UEFI and make sure your system is fully updated as well.

Comment: My system and UEFI (BIOS) are both fully updated to latest versions.

Comment: Do you have swap space? At least as much as RAM? `free` will show both. Read `man mkswap swapon`.

Comment: Seems like there is swap space, but not enough. Just 1GB but RAM is 8GB.

output of free
               total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:         8005444     2184380     2392008      654832     3429056     4917316
Swap:         999420           0      999420

swapon gives:

NAME      TYPE      SIZE USED PRIO
/dev/dm-2 partition 976M   0B   -2

Unfortunately, I don't know how to increase swap here. I don't see any swap-partition in graphical discs software. I selected encryption during installation and did not manually change partitions.